# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)

Tags: 14.04, mysql

While entering MySQL server I am getting an error like this:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
```

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: How you enter mysql server?

Answer (score 0):

> If your file my.cnf (usually in the */etc/mysql/* folder) is correctly
>   configured with
>
> ```
> socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
> ```
>
> you can check if mysql is running with the following command:
>
> ```
> mysqladmin -u root -p status
> ```
>
> try changing your permission to mysql folder. If you are working
>   locally, you can try:
>
> ```
> sudo chmod -R 755 /var/lib/mysql/
> ```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38